# Adjective for family-friendly jokes?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Kind of sincere, earnest, like you might find in a kids' movie; homely, a little banal, or... it's on the tip of my tongue!

Comment: Possibly *corny*?

Comment: A [dad joke](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dad_joke)?

Comment: Please supply an example of the type of joke you mean.

Comment: Perhaps ***clean***?

Comment: How about *G-rated*?

Comment: There are a number of slang terms.. "clean", "dad joke", "tasteful", "PG", etc. More formally you can call it an "age-appropriate joke", or an "inoffensive joke"... but then again everything is relative. Some cultures find things offensive that the US wouldn't (for example).

Comment: How about _wholesome_?

Comment: I agree with Opie that there's a term I've heard used, but it's not coming to me right now.  Kind of the opposite of "blue".

Comment: Is it not odd that the principal requirement for a joke to be "family-friendly" is that it avoid all mention of or allusion to the very thing that brings families into being?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast "Wholesome" is exactly what I was forgetting!! I feel like an idiot. Thanks. Now I'm not sure how to resolve the question.

Comment: @Toph - Oh, I can make it easy for you. I've created an answer and you can select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wholesome** would seem to fit, with its' associations with G-rated family appropriateness.

Answer (score 1):

If these two suggestions for **family-friendly jokes**  are not be quite right, the synonyms may help.

***larking*** Google source
(informal Brit.)
gerund or present participle: larking

> enjoy oneself by behaving in a playful and mischievous way. "he's
>   always joking and larking about in the office"
>   *synonyms*: fool
>   about/around, play tricks, indulge in horseplay, make mischief, monkey
>   about/around, footle about/around, clown about/around, have fun,
>   cavort, caper, romp, frolic, skylark;

***ribbing*** from Merriam-Webster  (adjective)

> marked by or expressive of mild or good-natured teasing "the lightly
>   ribbing tone tipped me off that this wasn't a serious reprimand"

Synonyms of *ribbing*

> bantering, chaffing, fooling, funning, jesting, joking,
>   joshing, kidding, rallying, razzing, ribbing.

Answer (score 0):

Another (ostentatious) option that occurs to me, after some hunting, is **anodyne**.

> adjective: not likely to provoke dissent or offense; inoffensive, often deliberately so: *anodyne New Age music* | *I attempted to keep the conversation as anodyne as possible.*